# Modifying admin login

Tags: magento

I want to add a simple link in form of a button to my admin login. The default view, `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml`, includes the following line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

Is there any way to hook into this line and render a template here? I've already tried this in my `app/code/local/<vendor>/<package>/etc/config.xml`

```
     <layout>
        <default>
            <reference name="root">
                <block type="core/template" name="form.additional.info" template="login.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

But sadly this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to add your simple link or phtml file in login box, right?

Comment: Simple link, yep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom phtml file using refrence block functionality of magento like this.

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\YOURLAYOUT.xml

<adminhtml_index_login>
   <reference name="form.additional.info">
      <block type="core/template" name="YOURCUSTOMNAME" template="your.phtml" />
   </reference> 
</adminhtml_index_login>
```

In `"your.phtml"`

You need to put your link to show there.

Comment: Where to put the `your.phtml`? It's weird to use a layout file far outside my extension directory...

Comment: you need to put that "your.phtml" in your extension template folder and then specify path according to that.

Comment: What do you mean by specify path? Sorry to ask such questions, today is my first (and hopefully last *cough*) day with Magento ;)...

Comment: Means your newly created .phtml file located in "app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template" folder.

Comment: Can't I just put the layout xml in one of my `app/code/local/<vendor>/<package>/etc` xml files? And the `*.phtml` file also?

Comment: you need to create admin layout.xml file in your custom extension at "app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout" and then template file as well.

Comment: Weird, but okay. Last question: I've added my `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/<package>.xml` and the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/<package>.phtml` but nothing is displayed. I guess I'm missing the point to tell Magento to load these files - but where/how to do this?

Comment: To tell magento to load your file, you need to add code in your app/code/local/<vendor>/<package>/etc/config.xml file.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nehalist/25b99b9d7a6a6b9730151d503f67c46b doesn't work :/

Comment: replace <frontend> with <adminhtml>. I think you don't know how to add layout file in magento admin side. But this change work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135162/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-nehalist).